# Two simple questions about test project with AndroidTestCase

Tags: android, performance, unit-testing, junit, android-testing

In my Android Test project, I have several test cases which extends `AndroidTestCase`:

**MyProjectTest structure:**

```
src/
  - TestCaseOne.java
  - TestCaseTwo.java
  - TestCaseThre.java
  - ...
```

In each of my test case, I have `setUp()`, `runTest()` & `tearDown()` phases:

```
public class TestCaseX extends AndroidTestCase{
    public void setUp(){
      ...
    }

    public void runTest(){
      ..
    }  

    public void tearDown(){
      ...
    }
}
```

I have two questions concerning these test cases:

**1.** If I run the test project as a whole, it runs each test case one by one starting from the top one (TestCaseOne.java) , how can I control the running order?

**2.** I have some logics which are common for all test cases' `setUp()` phases, how can I define a project level `setUp()` in which I could put all these common parts? (is it possible for `tearDown()` too?)

Comment: To **2.**: Can't you make an abstract class that implements `setUp()` and then extend that class with your three testcases?

Comment: Hi, MalaKa, yes, I can, I am just curious whether Android Test Framework provided such feature which I can directly use.

Comment: Another reason is that those common parts only need to be run once instead of for each test case. So, it would be nice if there is a project level setUp()